# Python- Average Rainfall

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code for average rainfall that I have been trying to figure out with the user entering the rainfall per month. But I keep getting this error code:

```
  File "/Users/brittneybutcher/Desktop/UM-Flint/Average Rainfall.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Average rainfall: " + format( averagerainfall, ".2f" ) )
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' "
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

```
for currentyear in range( 1, usernumberofyears + 1):
    for currentmonth in range( 1, 13):
        monthlyrainfallinches = float( input( "Please type the inches of rainfall for month " + \
                                              format( currentmonth, "d" ) + ", year " + format( currentyear, "d" ) + \
                                              ": " ) )
        totalinchesofrainfall += monthlyrainfallinches
        totalnumberofmonths += 1

averagerainfall = totalinchesofrainfall / totalnumberofmonths

print( "Number of Months: " + format( totalnumberofmonths, "d"), "Total inches of rainfall: " \
       + format( totalinchesofrainfall, ".2f" ), + \
       "Average rainfall: " + format( averagerainfall, ".2f" ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your second to last line you have both `+` and `,` together. The final print statement should read:

```
print( "Number of Months: " + format( totalnumberofmonths, "d"), "Total inches of rainfall: " \
       + format( totalinchesofrainfall, ".2f" ), \
       "Average rainfall: " + format( averagerainfall, ".2f" ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra '+' on the second to last line in your print statement. I'd suggest breaking up the formatting of the individual components to make this a bit more readable.

Something like the following should work:

```
monthStr = format( totalnumberofmonths, "d")
inchStr = format(totalinchesofrainfall, ".2f")
avgStr = format( averagerainfall, ".2f" ) 
print("Number of months: {0}\tTotal inches: {1}\tAverage rainfall: {2}".format(monthStr, inchStr, avgStr))
```